# jquery stop() causes hover effects to stop

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using the code at http://jsfiddle.net/eSbps/ I am having an issue.

Basically its a menu system that, when you hover over the top levels, the second levels are shown through slideDown('slow');

however to remove the queuing effect i am using `stop(true, false)`.

The issue is that when you hover over it again, the animation will only run to the point it was stopped at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the queuing effect, change your slideDown selector to `ul:not(:animated)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach: http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't [`.stop(true, false)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) with a slide like that, you have to make it go all the way using [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or the previous height is going to be the value it stopped at (*not* the original value), and is what it'll animate back to.